# AWS Cloudformation Template for Oracle and Dataguard Install Invariably Fails

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have been attempting to install oracle db 12c (both 12.2.0.1 as well as 12.1.0.2) But keep getting errors that I can't figure out. I have gone through AWS's own cloudformation troubleshooting guide along with several forums.

I am getting the following messages in the events log. I have included text below as well as a screen shot of the events for the root stack:

The following resource(s) failed to create: [OracleStack].

Embedded stack arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:007849015507:stack/Oracle-Database-OracleStack-1W5U4RT91JZXT/a1f67bb0-be05-11e9-8c50-02ee71065ed8 was not successfully created: The following resource(s) failed to create: [PrimaryInstance].

I have come accross some info on cloudformation helper scripts and timing out of parameters, but no topic addresses how to correct the problem.

Help is appreciated

[image: Screen Shot of Events on root stack page]

Comment: https://old.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/94lb5z/cloudformation_troubleshooting/

Comment: Can you find the embedded stack `OracleStack` in the CloudFormation console? It might be here: https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=us-west-2#/stacks/stackinfo?&stackId=arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:007849015507:stack/Oracle-Database-OracleStack-1W5U4RT91JZXT/a1f67bb0-be05-11e9-8c50-02ee71065ed8

Comment: Posting the CloudFormation templates for both the parent stack, `Oracle-Database`, and the embedded stack, `OracleStack`, would be helpful information as well

Comment: I have contacted the people who wrote the quickstart guide and opened a ticket with AWS using my support plan. The initial support personnel got the exact same error that I did. This means that the quickstart is most likely outdated now.If anyone is able to get the quickstart to work, please let me know.

Comment: This quickstart guide? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/oracle-database/welcome.html

Comment: The template for the nested stack, `OracleStack`, seems to be here: https://aws-quickstart.s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-oracle-database/templates/oracle-database.template

Comment: Correct. That's the template that I have been using. Have you tried launching that tempate and, if so, is it working for you?